# Anatomy of a UI Elements?

Tags: guidelines, scrollbars, style-guide

Where can I find documentation on the anatomy of UI elements, such as:

- **Button**: label, hit space
- **Scroll Bars**: track, thumb, up / down arrows
- **Progress Bars**: track, progress
- **Slider**: track, thumb
- etc.

I would like something like below, but dissecting UI elements *instead of* typography.
[image: Play Type's typography glossary]
Taken from [Play Type's typography glossary](https://playtype.com/about/typefaces/glossary).

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I can think of to what you're looking for are Interface Guidelines.

A good example of this is Apple's iOS 7 Human Interface Guidelines, specifically the [controls](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW1) section. They have lots of pictures of UI elements with call outs, descriptions of how they are meant to be used, and defining characteristics.

[image: OS X Menu Interface guidelines]

Other sources:

1. [iOS 7 Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW1)
2. [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Menus/Menus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000356-TP6)
3. [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/stable/)
4. [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html)
5. [Elementary OS Human Interface Guidelines](http://elementaryos.org/docs/human-interface-guidelines/buttons)

Comment: The image is great! The sources you included are are informative, but way too verbose for what I'm looking for. I'm tempted to make a cheat sheet, but that gets back to my root question of what are the names of the individual aspects found in UI components.